# VBA: How to loop through all Gantt Bar Styles in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am currently working on a VBA macro that will configure Gantt Bar Styles in MS Project. Turns out I can't simply use a template because I have to import XML data from an online app, and doing an import into an existing project file messes up the outline levels. So I have to import it into a new project, and then reconfigure appearances and bar styles.

Project VBA has a series of GanttBarStyle methods in the Application object. But I can't seem to find an object containing the bar styles, that I can simply iterate through, that will give me a count of all the bar styles, etc. Something similar to the tasks object: you use the object to get a count, then loop using that count or simply loop through individual task objects, etc.

For example let's say I want to completely delete all bar styles for the current view. Most I've come up with is:

```
Sub barex()

For a = 1 To 200
    On Error GoTo RoutineEnd
    result = Application.GanttBarStyleDelete(1)
Next

RoutineEnd:


End Sub
```

Which seems like a pretty messy way of doing it... simply delete the first bar style, 200 times, and if you get an error break the loop.

And something like that, of course, doesn't help if I need to check individual bar styles for a given name, or bar position, or things of the sort.

Is there such a thing as a Gantt Bar Styles object in Project VBA?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such a thing as a Gantt Bar Styles object in Project VBA?

Unfortunately, this is an example of the api being incomplete. There is no collection object for Gantt bars.

---

Instead, focus on fixing the original problem. There are many ways to get data into an existing project (or a new file created from a template) such as:

- import into a new project and then copy to existing project
- update the project bit by bit using vba
- put the xml data in Excel first and then use the Import Wizard

At least one of these will be better than building new Gantt bars in VBA.